# How to do a mysql affinity query with various terms taken from an array in laravel

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, laravel, eloquent

I have an array indexed with 16 terms, I need mysql to find articles related to or corresponding to these 16 terms or at least one of them.

In laravel there is no "IN", there is "whereIn" and he only accepts a string and I can't create a string with 16 terms, because he doesn't recognize the comma, I'm using php 7.4 and the tolerance seems to be lower. I tried to transform the array into a string with implode (), but it doesn't work, it returns a "convert array to string" error, looking at the documentation I found something related to collection, however, it doesn't accept, it really has to be a string . I tried to use orWhere and, although it doesn't return an error, it doesn't display the result and takes a long time to process.
The array is an indexed array in the standard model:

array (['1', '2', '3' ...]);

In addition to the terms, I need to check if the articles are from the current user, this is working, remembering that the array and its contents are fixed, are in the controller.

```
  $link = (['title', 'category', 'description', 'body', 'jobs', 'colors', 'phone', 'about', 'shopping', 'trade', 'costumers', 'author', 'online', 'cloud', 'technology', 'company']);
            $linkt = My::where('id', $user->id)->whereIn($link);
```

or

```
    $linkt = My::where('id', $user->id)->whereIn('from', 'LIKE', '%' . $link);
```

or

```
$test = implode(",", $link);
$linkt = My::where('id', $user->id)->whereIn($test);
```

These things don't work for me.

Comment: Laravel whereIn accepts an array...eg: `$users = DB::table('users')
                    ->whereIn('id', [1, 2, 3])
                    ->get();`

Comment: I can't include the entire controller, but I'll put the search function and the array in the question

Comment: First parameter of whereIn needs to be column name. Second parameter array of values you want to match against.

Comment: ParseError
syntax error, unexpected ','   (whereIn('from', $link);)  It didn't work, do you think it's better to put the array inside whereIn ()?

Comment: Even placing the array inside whereIn () it returns an empty array [], I have 10 results corresponding to these words, they are in a text, in the from column, they are different records.

Comment: I meant to correct your statement about whereIn not expecting an array.. In your case, I dont think you can put `like` queries inside a whereIn.

Comment: print () returns [] and print_r () returns Illuminate \ Database \ Eloquent \ Collection Object ([items: protected] => Array ()), any alternative methods?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are building a search query, why don't you build the query after looping through the links (search terms) array?

Something like this:

```
$link = (['title', 'category', 'description', 'body', 'jobs', 'colors', 'phone', 'about', 'shopping', 'trade', 'costumers', 'author', 'online', 'cloud', 'technology', 'company']);

$link = collect($link);

$query = My::where('id', $user->id)->where('from', 'like', '%'.$link[0].'%';

$link->shift(); // remove first element since it's used

$link->each(function($item) use ($query){
  $query->orWhere('from', 'LIKE', '%'.$item.'%'); //assuming that 'from' is your column name
} );

$query->get(); //to retrieve the results
```

Another option is to use `whereRaw` to send in a raw statement deduced by imploding the array. Something like this:

```
$link = ([..]); //link array
$linkImploded = implode("%' OR '%", $link);
$finalLikeStatement = "from LIKE '%{$linkImploded}%'";

My::where('id', $user->id)->whereRaw($finalLikeStatement)->get();
```

Comment: Thanks, this works, but I fear that a loop due to multiple requests can slow the application down, I will certainly have to create a queue for this, I will see a few more things about it before implementing it.

Comment: added another option. But, if you are worried about performance, `LIKE` is not the approach you would probably want. I recommend looking into full text searching.

Comment: I forgot to ask, this only generates one result per term, how do I get them all back?

Comment: `get()` returns all that matches. If you are getting 1 result, it probably means that there is one result that matches all these conditions. To ensure, why don't you run the raw query in mysql client and see if it produces more results?

Comment: This line is giving me error, it seems that the version of mysql is incompatible, I am looking for something similar to be able to test. -> $finalLikeStatement

Comment: You can get the raw sql statement to use using `toSql()` instead of get. As in: `My::where('id', $user->id)->whereRaw($finalLikeStatement)->toSql();` Use that in the mysql client.